# Can't find myDockPanel.DockAsMdiDocument()

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

I can't find DockAsMdiDocument() method of my dockPanel. I added all available DevExpress references but still there is no such function.

I want my docPanel fill my form in load event ( because I know its not possible to do this in design view ). Am I missing something ? How can I do it without DockAsMdiDocument method ?

I'm using DevExpress Version 11.1.4 for C3 with Visual Studio 2010 on windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using DockAsMdiDocument alternatively you can dock a DockPanel by creating new Document object like the following:

```
myDockPanel.Dock = DockingStyle.Float; //this is because DocumentManager can dock only floating DockPanel, because it works with forms.
Document doc = tabbedView1.Controller.RegisterDockPanel(myDockPanel.FloatForm) as Document;
tabbedView1.Controller.Dock(doc);
```

Put this on dockManager's Load event if you want to use this code on the start up.

Comment: Also, dockAsMdiParet method is only available in DevExpress 11.1.5 or higher.